# TFS will not execute NuGet script

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget, agent

So I finally got my hands on TFS, build a small app with some tests (NUnit) and wanted to let TFS build it for me.
However, the build fails when it tries to use NuGet:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Build
******************************************************************************
Executing the following commandline:
C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\agent\worker\vsoWorker.exe  /name:Worker-6726df74-da4c-466a-b1c6-1f2b78b88a8d /id:6726df74-da4c-466a-b1c6-1f2b78b88a8d /rootFolder:"C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent" /logger:Forwarding,1.0.0;Verbosity=Verbose,Name=Agent4-bbf8df0bd72035f895b9972ec79f2bcb;JobId=6726df74-da4c-466a-b1c6-1f2b78b88a8d
******************************************************************************
Starting: Get sources
******************************************************************************
Syncing repository: RABs Git test (Git)
Starting fetch...
Checking out 1f6c87dfd38578b9d0f365f83a92fc4ef9bc172e to C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\_work\1\s
Checked out branch refs/heads/master for repository RABs Git test at commit 1f6c87dfd38578b9d0f365f83a92fc4ef9bc172e
******************************************************************************
Running tasks
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: NuGet restore GitDemoProject.sln
******************************************************************************
Set workingFolder to default: C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18
Executing the powershell script: C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1
Attempting to perform the NormalizeRelativePath operation on the 'FileSystem' provider failed for path 'C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18'. Access is denied
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: NuGetInstaller
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
******************************************************************************
Set workingFolder to default: C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13
fs.js:887
  return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\rab'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:887:18)
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1518:21)
    at toRealPath (module.js:126:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:165:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: CopyFiles
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Publish Artifact: drop
******************************************************************************
Set workingFolder to default: C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28
fs.js:887
  return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\rab'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:887:18)
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1518:21)
    at toRealPath (module.js:126:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:165:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: PublishBuildArtifacts
******************************************************************************
Task NuGetInstaller failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
******************************************************************************
Finishing Build
******************************************************************************
```

It is the line `Attempting to perform the NormalizeRelativePath operation on the 'FileSystem' provider failed for path 'C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18'. Access is denied` which gives the first blow. 
I tried to run that, which gave a lot of errors as well:

```
PS C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18> .\NuGetInstaller.ps1
import-module : The specified module 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal' was not loaded because no
 valid module file was found in any module directory.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1:12 char:1
+ import-module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Microsoft.TeamF...k.Task.Internal:String) [Import-Module], FileNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

import-module : The specified module 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Common' was not loaded because no v
alid module file was found in any module directory.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1:13 char:1
+ import-module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Common"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Microsoft.TeamF...ask.Task.Common:String) [Import-Module], FileNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\VsoNuGetHelper.ps1:3 char:33
+ $nuGetTempDirectory = Join-Path $Env:SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY "NuGet\"
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCom
   mand

Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\VsoNuGetHelper.ps1:4 char:34
+ $tempNuGetConfigPath = Join-Path $nuGetTempDirectory "newNuGet.config"
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCom
   mand

Get-LocalizedString : The term 'Get-LocalizedString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
 again.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1:26 char:12
+     throw (Get-LocalizedString -Key "Solution parameter must be set")
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LocalizedString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Convert-String : The term 'Convert-String' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operabl
e program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1:29 char:21
+ $b_excludeVersion = Convert-String $excludeVersion Boolean
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Convert-String:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Convert-String : The term 'Convert-String' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operabl
e program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1:30 char:14
+ $b_noCache = Convert-String $noCache Boolean
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Convert-String:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Get-LocalizedString : The term 'Get-LocalizedString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
 again.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1:54 char:12
+     throw (Get-LocalizedString -Key "No solution was found using search pattern  ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LocalizedString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Get-ToolPath : The term 'Get-ToolPath' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable pr
ogram. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1:65 char:18
+     $nuGetPath = Get-ToolPath -Name 'NuGet.exe';
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ToolPath:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Get-LocalizedString : The term 'Get-LocalizedString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
 again.
At C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18\NuGetInstaller.ps1:70 char:12
+     throw (Get-LocalizedString -Key "Unable to locate {0}" -ArgumentList 'nuget. ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LocalizedString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\rab\Desktop\BuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.18>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer [found here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f13182ec-7132-49e2-a872-0356783fe353/tfs-2015-update-2-local-build-agent-throws-access-is-denied-exception-on-normalizerelativepath-in?forum=tfsbuild), but I don't know exactly why this is the solution.

Move the agent-folder (with `Agent`, `task`, `ConfigureAgent.cmd`...) into `c:\SomeName`, and you are good.